# React Native - Insert data to database is not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have 3 kinds of data in my codes, first is the states, the thing with "index" ( Sorry, I dunno what to call it. ), last is data from my database.

In my states, actually I have no problem with states. I can those thing in my database smoothly... But things change when I try to send my other data to my database.

Here I'm trying to send my data with "index" in my database. I'm not sure if I'm doing it in right construction of code, and also I'm having an error here which say's " Can't Find Variable; index ".

```
submit = () => {
            fetch('http://192.168.254.100:3308/SendOrder/Send', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    order_quantity: this.state['count'+index],
                    special_request: this.state['SplOrder'+index],
                })
            }).then(res => res.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
                    console.log(responseJson);
                })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}
return(
    <View>
         <TextInput
         onChangeText = { (text) => this.setState({ ['SplOrder'+index]: text }) }
         value = { this.state['SplOrder'+index] }
         />
         <TextInput
         onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({ ['count'+index]: text}) }
         value={ this.state['count'+index] }
         />
    </View>
)
```

Lastly, here I'm trying also to send my data that is from my database back to my database. I have two URL in my code, the first one is for my display and the second is for choosing items.

```
fetchData = async () => {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.***.***:3308/categories/" + params.id + params.price);
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json })          // Simply for display
}

submit = () => {                          // For Sending items
            fetch('http://192.168.254.100:3308/SendOrder/Send', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    menu_desc: this.state.id,
                    menu_price: this.state.price,
                })
            }).then(res => res.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
                    console.log(responseJson);
                })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}
<View>
    <Text>Name: { item.menu_desc }</Text>
    <Text>Price: ₱{ item.menu_price }</Text>
</View>
```

Here, with;

```
menu_desc: this.state.id
menu_price: this.state.price
```

output would be like:

```
menu_desc: [],
menu_price: []
```

So I think, the states here is not working because my output is empty. So I tried it like this;

```
menu_desc: this.item.menu_desc,
menu_price: this.item.price
```

But with this I'm having an error which say's; Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.item.menu_desc')

**So to cut the long story short**, what is the proper way to this, guys? Because I know what I'm doing here is none sense, and I'm so sorry for that. :(

Comment: I would highly recommend restructuring this. I like the redux pattern, personally. It makes it very easy to follow the follow of data and separate out where the issue is. as well as reusing certain pieces of code.

Comment: what is the console log for this when you log it out?

Comment: @TallPaul for my indexs it is error because I'm not sure what is the proper way to do it with indexs and in my data from my database it is empty output/array.

Comment: can you console log your state and share that?